# AssertionError: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, datareader

I got the assertation error for the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader.data as web
stocks = ['AMZN','TCEHY']
start = dt.datetime(2019, 6, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2020, 6, 1)
data = web.DataReader(stocks,data_source='yahoo',start=start, end= end)['Adj Close']
```

this is the error message that I got:

```
> AssertionError: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
```

any feedback is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Upgrade pandas and or pandas_datareader. This ran without any issues for me, using pandas 1.1.2 and 0.9.0 for datareader.

Comment: many thanks, it worked for me